# Mule HTTP read timeout redirect

Tags: exception, redirect, timeout, mule

I'm trying to cause a responseTimeout Exception intentionally by allowing a short http response timeout on outbound endpoint. When timeout occurs, I want to redirect to a error message page as shown below. However, I get only exception messages as response and never get redirected to the page I assigned. Any ideas? Thanx

```
<flow name="userflow" processingStrategy="synchronous" doc:name="">
    <http:inbound-endpoint host="${server_id}" port="8091" responseTimeout="100"
        path="${path}/nexonplayrock" exchange-pattern="request-response" doc:name="HTTP" />
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost"
        port="8091" path="${path}/test" method="POST" responseTimeout="1"
        mimeType="application/json" >
    </http:outbound-endpoint>
    <choice-exception-strategy >
       <catch-exception-strategy when="exception.causedBy(java.net.SocketTimeoutException)" doc:description="Response Timeout">
       <logger level="INFO" message="HTTP Response Timed Out!" doc:name="Logger"/>                              
           <http:response-builder status="302" doc:name="HTTP Response Builder">
               <http:location value="${path2}/error" />
           </http:response-builder>             
       </catch-exception-strategy>          
    </choice-exception-strategy>        
</flow>
```

Comment: Did the processing reach the catch exception strategy when the exception is thrown? Did you see the logger from the exception strategy printed?

Comment: Yes, and didnt get redirected to the error page.

Comment: can you post the http client code? the client will perform the redirect.